# Cleaning URL in php

Tags: php, url

I have set of URLs that I need to import them into database but there are some variables passed in these URLs (Google Tracking codes) and I'm trying to clean automatically.

URL Example: http://canadaam.ctvnews.ca/health/online-test-for-alzheimer-s-measuring-your-cognitive-health-1.1914180&ct=ga&cd=CAIyAA&usg=AFQjCNFZKDiQeiP0vhyBKcqssn9Zz8Lhqg

So as you can see I need to clear anything here

> "&ct=ga&cd=CAIyAA&usg=AFQjCNFZKDiQeiP0vhyBKcqssn9Zz8Lhqg"

I do understand that I can clear this using str_replace but this only works if all codes within url are similar and as we all know each URL could have its own code therefore I am looking for a solution or any guidance in regards to how to resolved this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that URL doesn't look right to me..

Comment: Yes, it lacks the `?`. Typo ?

Comment: Its a copy from Google Feed

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Google Feed, I found the same 404 type of urls in our logs and I was wondering if the missing \? character was due to our mistake or a bad request. Please share more info if you have any. In the meantime I suggest you to rewrite via htaccess (if you use Apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't care about any of the URL parameters you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

e.g. Something like this should work:

```
$url = "http://canadaam.ctvnews.ca/health/online-test-for-alzheimer-s-measuring-your-cognitive-health-?1.1914180&ct=ga&cd=CAIyAA&usg=AFQjCNFZKDiQeiP0vhyBKcqssn9Zz8Lhqg";

$urlArray = explode("?", $url);

echo $urlArray[0];
```

Comment: I just added a ? in the above example, using & or any other character that you are sure will not occur before the end of the section you want will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, ok this works, I thought of this but what if I check if CT exists then clear the value as GA,CT,USG are all exist on most URLs

Comment: Dean, thanks for update but what if a URL already has & within URL and  follows by Google code?

Comment: If all the URLs have exactly the same Google params added (ct, cd, usg) and in the same order then you can use explode() with a delimiter of "&ct=ga" which will you you your original URL + any params that come with it. The only problem with this is if the Google added params change. If they do and there are only a few variations, then you may still be able to use this approach but you would have to add a step first to check the string for which format it is in and thus which delimiter should be used.

Comment: You could also use a combination of strpos() and substr() in this case which might actually be better than explode as you only want the first portion of the string.

Comment: Thanks Dean, great direction and is logical. I look into it and try to post my result here

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$url = 'http://canadaam.ctvnews.ca/health/online-test-for-alzheimer-s-measuring-your-cognitive-health-1.1914180?ct=ga&cd=CAIyAA&usg=AFQjCNFZKDiQeiP0vhyBKcqssn9Zz8Lhqg';

$parts = parse_url($url);
unset($parts['query']);
echo unparse_url($parts);


function unparse_url($parts_arr) {
   if (strcmp($parts_arr['scheme'], '') != 0) {
     $ret_url = $parts_arr['scheme'] . '://';
   }
   $ret_url .= $parts_arr['user'];
   if (strcmp($parts_arr['pass'], '') != 0) {
     $ret_url .= ':' . $parts_arr['pass'];
   }
   if ((strcmp($parts_arr['user'], '') != 0) || (strcmp($parts_arr['pass'], '') != 0)) {
     $ret_url .= '@';
   }
   $ret_url .= $parts_arr['host'];
   if (strcmp($parts_arr['port'], '') != 0) {
     $ret_url .= ':' . $parts_arr['port'];
   }
   $ret_url .= $parts_arr['path'];
   if (strcmp($parts_arr['query'], '') != 0) {
         $ret_url .= '?' . $parts_arr['query'];
       }
       if (strcmp($parts_arr['fragment'], '') != 0) {
         $ret_url .= '#' . $parts_arr['fragment'];
     }

   return $ret_url;
 }
```

function found at http://saatske.demon.nl/vanWWW/php/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thanks, I can see your solution but it doesn't return anything except original URL

Comment: The url is not correct in your question - you need to replace the first & with a ?  try to browse both versions (yours and mine) and you will see one works and the other doesn't!

Comment: Indeed, but my point is, this is a code from Google Feed, this is a third party website and & or /& is not generated in my code, this is a URL I get from Google Alerts - any solution for that?

Comment: check for instance of ? in the url.  if it is not there replace the first occurrence of & with ?